# Unexpected token when using json

Tags: javascript, json

I have encoded JSON (using `encodeURIComponent`) string:

```
%5B%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_1%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_2%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_3%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_4%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_5%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%20(%D1%81%D0%BC)%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_6%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%20(%D0%BA%D0%B3)%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_7%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_8%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20IQ%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_9%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_10%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_11%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%92%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_12%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_13%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_14%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84.%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_15%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_16%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_17%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%A2%D0%92%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_18%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_19%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_20%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_21%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_22%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_23%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_24%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_25%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_26%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_27%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_28%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_29%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8E%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_30%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_31%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_32%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%5D%5B%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_1%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_2%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_3%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_4%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_5%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%20(%D1%81%D0%BC)%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_6%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%20(%D0%BA%D0%B3)%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_7%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_8%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20IQ%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22120%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_9%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_10%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_11%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%92%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_12%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%220%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_13%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_14%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84.%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%2215%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_15%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%2211%22%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_16%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_17%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%A2%D0%92%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_18%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_19%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_20%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_21%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_22%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_23%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_24%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%A3%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_25%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_26%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_27%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_28%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_29%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8E%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_30%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22no%22%2C%22date_first%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_second%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_31%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%2C%7B%22question_id%22%3A%22survey_id_32%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22%D0%AF%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2C%22answer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date_first%22%3Anull%2C%22date_second%22%3Anull%7D%5Dnodata
```

In decoded way it should look sth like:

```
var survey = [
   {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "мммм", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
   {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "вввв", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
   {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "ьььь", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
   {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "йййй", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null}
    // ...
]
```

I encode my survey using function:

```
function survey_to_arrays(obj) {
    return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

And decode:

```
function arrays_to_list(arraysJSONString) {
    var l = []
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(arraysJSONString)) // Unexpected token [
    
    var d = {}
    var lastindex = 0
    for (var key in jsonObj) {
        var q_id = jsonObj[key].question_id
        var q = jsonObj[key].question
        var a = jsonObj[key].answer
        var df = jsonObj[key].date_first
        var ds = jsonObj[key].date_second
        d["question_id"] = q_id
        d["question"] = q
        d["answer"] = a
        d["date_first"] = df
        d["date_second"] = ds
        
        // l[lastindex].push(d)
        l.push(d)
        lastindex++
        d = {}
    }
    return l
}
```

Encoding is ok, but when I try to decode  this survey it returns me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON ...` in `arrays_to_list` function, I put comment on the row where error occures. What can be wrong?

**EDIT 1**

Actually I do this:

First save answers (JSON encoded string) to MySQL datadase

```
var jsonAnswersString = survey_to_arrays(answers)
function saveAnswersToDB(str) {
    // APPEND FORM DATA
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('answer_string', str);

    // AJAX CALL
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "../php/save_answer.php", true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
    //   console.log("AJAX responce text :", this.response);
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

And then I try to get this answers back:

```
data = getdata()
function getdata() {
    // APPEND FORM DATA
    var result
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('req', 'get');

    // AJAX CALL
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', "../php/get_answer.php", true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        // result = this.responseText
        console.log("AJAX RESPONCE IN SURVEY IS", this.responseText)
        result = arrays_to_string(this.responseText)
    };
    xhr.send(data);
    console.log("AJAX RESPONSE DECODED : ",result)
    return []
}
```

`save_answer.php` file:

```
<?php

function getNewNumOfTries($id) {
    include("config.php");
    $con = setConnection();
    $query    = "SELECT num_of_tries FROM `survey_results` WHERE user_id='$id'";
    $n   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $biggest_n = -1;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($n)) {
        // echo $biggest_n . "  " . $row['num_of_tries'] . "|||";
        if ($biggest_n < $row['num_of_tries']) {
            $biggest_n = $row['num_of_tries'];
        };
    }

    if ($biggest_n == -1) {
        $biggest_n += 2;
    }
    else {
        $biggest_n++;
    }
    $con->close();
    return $biggest_n;
}

// set connection
include("get_from_db_functions.php");

// get json string and other var's
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
$id            = $_COOKIE['id'];
$answer_string = $_POST['answer_string'];
$date          = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$num_of_tries  = getNewNumOfTries($id);

$con = setConnection();


// json string to array
// $jsonArray = json_decode($answer_string, true);
// array to db
include("config.php");
$con = new mysqli($db_ip, $db_login, $db_pwd, $db_name);
$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO survey_results (user_id, num_of_tries, date, results) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $num_of_tries, $date, $answer_string);
/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();
/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

// close connection
$con->close();

?>
```

`get_answer.php`

```
<?php

include("config.php");
include("get_from_db_functions.php");
$con = setConnection();
$query    = "SELECT MAX(num_of_tries) as maxn FROM `survey_results` WHERE user_id='$id'";
$n   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$biggest_n = -1;
$results = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($n)) {
    $biggest_n = $row['maxn'];
    $id = $_COOKIE["id"];
    $query    = "SELECT results FROM `survey_results` WHERE user_id='$id'";
    $answers  = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($answers)) {
        $results = $row2['results'];
        echo $results;
    }
}

echo "nodata";

$con->close();

?>
```

*PS I know that I should use PDO*

My user id is right and = 42

[image]

**Edit 2**

Content of `this.responseText` in xhr.onload is the same string I posted that is encoded in the begining of the question:

Comment: Can you post the content of `console.log(this.responseText)` inside your ajax callback

Comment: @Greedo please see my edit 2

Comment: @Aquill try to run `decodeURIComponent` simply to see the decoded output `var jsonObj = decodeURIComponent(arraysJSONString)`. Once you are satisfied with the decoded value then perform `JSON.parse`

Comment: @Shiladitya decoded output is `[{"question_id":"survey_id_1","question":"Страна проживания","answer":"","date_first":null,"date_second":null}, ...etc... ]` string, it is ok, but when I add `JSON.parse(...decodedstring...)` it returns me error unexpected token [

Comment: @Aquill Then validate you JSON in some online validator such as https://jsonlint.com/ . You are getting error because of JSON is not in correct format

Answer (score 0):

You sure are not doing anything in the middle? this code is working correctly:

```js
var survey = [
   {question_id: "survey_id_1", question: "мммм", answer: "1", date_first: null, date_second: null},
   {question_id: "survey_id_2", question: "вввв", answer: "2", date_first: null, date_second: null},
   {question_id: "survey_id_3", question: "ьььь", answer: "3", date_first: null, date_second: null},
   {question_id: "survey_id_4", question: "йййй", answer: "4", date_first: null, date_second: null}
];

function survey_to_arrays(obj) {
    return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))
}

function array_to_survey(str) { 
  return JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(str))
}

console.log(array_to_survey(survey_to_arrays(survey)))
```

Comment: And... I should not do all the stuff below `JSON.parse ...` ? It looks it work the same way but my function is huge!